# Get system arguments from calling file

Tags: python

Let's assume that I have a simple file named `foo`:

```
from logger import Logger


def foo_func():
    foo = Logger()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo_func()
```

`foo` is being launched with a system argument, for example, like this: `python foo.py --site=QA`

I have another file named `logger`:

```
import inspect

class Logger:

    def __init__(self):

        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        caller = inspect.getouterframes(frame)[-1][1]

        self.app_name = caller.rsplit('/', 1)[-1].split('.py')[0]

        print self.app_name
```

The way that it currently works, `self.app_name` is succesfully giving me `foo`, which is the name of the calling file, but how can I ALSO obtain the argument, which would be `--site=QA` that foo is being called with?

I know that I can just pass the system arguments when initializing the instance of Logger, however, I would really like to obtain them in a different manner. Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you just `import sys`, then access `sys.argv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import the `sys` module and check `sys.argv[]`:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1: # sys.argv[0] == the script name so we start from index 1
    for arg in sys.argv:
        print arg
```

and from the command line:

```
~$ python my_script.py some_arg some_other_arg
```

which outputs:

```
~$ my_script.py
~$ some_arg
~$ some_other_arg
```

Comment: Yes... this will work within foo, which I said I know, but my question is asking how I can get the execution arguments from foo IN logger

Comment: um.. as far as a i know, which ever script is the parent (executed from the command line with the args) will have the args. so just save them into variables and then pass them into any other module that needs them. ie, you have a script `logger` with a function `get_args(args)` and then in script `foo` that imports `logger` you just call `logger.get_args(parsed_args)` where `parsed_args` are the args collected using the sys module.

Comment: Just got on my computer and tried this. Wow... never would have expected it to work that way haha. I totally overlooked that as being an option so much so that I didn't even bother trying it. Sheesh.

Comment: meh, i do that all the time. glad it worked for you though, cheers!